# How can I send POST vars?

Tags: php

This is probably a stupid question but I need to ask it because I've never had to do this before.

There is a website that allows us to check the status of an order. We have been having to do this manually by going to this site and is very time consuming. I want to automate this task.

The site accepts only POST vars. Is there a way that I can send data to this site or is this not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use PHP CURL to do this. http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Thanks Liam. Is there a particular module in the CURL library that I should focus on?

Comment: Liam, I should have mentioned that this database we want to access is using SSL.

Comment: Hi, well, firstly the SSL is not a problem, as this can be accounted for when creating your CURL object. As for the modules: You initialise a cURL call using curl_init(), then set your parameters using curl_setopt or curl_setopt_array, then execute using curl_exec

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [CURL libraries in PHP](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php):

```
$postvars = array('name' => 'value');
$url = 'http://example.com';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, Slokun. Do I need to recompile PHP for cURL or does this work out of the box?

Comment: @Jim Assuming you have the cURL libraries compiled into PHP, then they will work out of the box. Run `phpinfo()` and do a search in there for `curl`. If it lists it, then it was compiled nicely. Otherwise, you'd need to either recompile or find a way to add them. There are POST methods without it (done them) but they're a lot more complicated.